# System.runas throwing insert failed error in test class

Tags: unit-test, dml, dmlexception, runas

The error is:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username.
> The username already exists in this or another Salesforce organization. Usernames must be unique across all Salesforce organizations. To resolve, use a different username (it doesn't need to match the user's email address). : [Username]
>   Class.testForActivityTrigger.testRunAs: line 11, column 1

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
Public class testForActivityTrigger{
    public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='BLP_NA'];

        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='test@testorg.com');

        System.runas(u){    
            Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Apex Test');
            insert acct;

            Task tsk1 = new Task(WhatId = acct.Id, Subject = 'Email: apex test', ActivityDate = date.today(), Status = 'Completed');
            insert tsk1;

            Property__c objProperty = new Property__c(name = 'Apex Test');
            insert objProperty;

            Property_Relation__c objPropRelation = new Property_Relation__c(Property__c = objProperty.id , Account__c =acct.Id );
            insert objPropRelation ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Let me guess... duplicate username.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Username field is unique across all orgs. Try using a value less likely to collide. Something like `testUser+asdfghjkl@example.com.1234ABCD`. You can randomize it more by adding static counters, `Math.random`, etc. Here are a couple options for your one-off case.

```
'testUser+asdfghjkl@example.com.' + Math.random()
'testUser+asdfghjkl@example.com.' + Datetime.now().getTime()
```

---

A refresher from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) for those who may have forgotten or not seen it:

> The runAs method implicitly inserts the user that is passed in as parameter if the user has been instantiated, but not inserted yet.

Comment: Yes, We need to make username unique across all orgs. One way is to use getTime() method. Then username could be written as UserName=System.now().getTime()+'systemadmin@testorg.com'. The getTime() method Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this DateTime object

Comment: @Devendra yes there are many workable approaches.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, you are correct :). There are many ways to make the unique username. This is the one I generally use.

Comment: Added a few concrete examples. It's more reliable than `random`, probably.